# When provisioning an on-premises database with Sync Framework I get 'Cannot update identity column i_OBJ_Identity'

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to sync an on-premis Sql Server 2008 R2 database to an Azure Sql Database. I've divided the syncs into scopes and provisioning and syncing works for most scopes but one gives me "Cannot update identity column 'i_OBJ_Identity'".

The schema for the table containing this column is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBJ_ObjectContentStaging](
    [i_OBJ_PublishedID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [i_OBJ_TypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [i_OBJ_ChannelID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ntx_OBJ_Content] [ntext] NULL,
    [nvc_OBJ_PreviewContent] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [i_OBJ_Identity] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [ts_OBJ_TimeStamp] [timestamp] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OBJ_ObjectContentStaging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [i_OBJ_PublishedID] ASC,
    [i_OBJ_TypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

So in this table the identity column is not the primary key.

What can I do to remedy this? I cannot change the schema of the source database and selecting the columns to sync on a per table basis would be a huge undertaking.

Please advice,
Mathias

Comment: if it's just a one way sync, why not simply take out the Identity settings on the Azure SQL part?

Comment: I ended up making an exclusion mechanism so I can specify which fields I don't want to include in the sync. There were only about five fields in as many tables.